# Not Found when rewriting using same rule as another rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a rewrite doing `article?id=10` which goes to `article/10` and I'm trying to do another like this.

I want to go from `site?=website.com` to `site/website.com`. Alright, seems like an easy task. So I do

```
RewriteRule ^site/([0-9]+)$ site.php?id=$1
```

Which is the same rule as the `article` rewrite basically. Now I go to `site/10` for example and I get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /site/sdfsd was not found on this server.

Why would this happen if it's the same thing as the other rewrite which works fine?....

Options -MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^site/([0-9]+)$ site.php?id=$1

# rewrite from /dir/file/ to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `site?=website.com` is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.+)$ site.php?id=$1 [L]
```

`[0-9]+` only matches numbers.

Comment: Check my edit with all my code. And I get `Undefined index: s`, so it isn't working.

Comment: Where do you get `Undefined index: s`? This looks as if it comes from php so the redirect is working.

Comment: You know, that if you open `site/website.com` you will be redirected to `site.php?id=website.com`? There is no string to ID conversion possible (only if you hardcode it into separate rewrite rules).

Answer (score 0):

Basically your rewriting rule is bad

`RewriteRule ^site/([0-9]+)$ site.php?id=$1` will only match numbers

You'll could use instead

`RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site.php?id=$1`

(wildcards)

And I'll have to say that the expression "site/whatever.com" points in reality to

site.php?id=whatever.com - reverse statement is false

Answer (score 0):

You rule does not match because the role only allow numbers. In other words your rule say:

Start with "site/" following a number (0-9).

Your rule must be

```
RewriteRule ^site/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ site.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two problems.

[0-9] only matches numbers, so it won't work with letters.

Also you need to add the [L] flag to your rules to make sure it stops at the first match.

```
RewriteRule ^site/(0-9a-zA-Z+)$ site.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I added all my code into the post